# Click on Next button and finally click on Continue button and break the loop in Selenium using Java

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to attempt quiz in learning web app. But I was stuck at the point where I need to attempt the quiz by clicking on the next button until the continue button appears, then clicking on the continue button and break the loop and come back to the previous loop.

Check out [this video](https://www.screencast.com/t/3Zsdwq0D7qt) of the app.

```
public int clickNextBtn() throws InterruptedException {
    int isContinueBtnDisplayed = 0;

    Thread.sleep(5000);
    if (lnkNextBtn.isDisplayed()) {
        System.out.println("***** Next button text is - " + lnkNextBtn.getText());
        System.out.println("***** Next button is displayed.");
        int nextBtnCount = 1;

        if (lnkContinueBtn.isDisplayed() == false) {
            lnkNextBtn.click();
            clickNextBtn();
            System.out.println("*****link next button is clicked.");
            System.out.println("*****link next button counter = " + nextBtnCount++);
        } else {

        }
    } else {
        lnkContinueBtn.click();
        clickNextBtn();
        isContinueBtnDisplayed = 1;
    }

    return isContinueBtnDisplayed;
}
```

Comment: What is the issue that you're getting? Also please add locators for the buttons?

Comment: Clicking on the **Next Button** is taking too long, so the script is getting slow to run all the test cases. Locators for the Next button is  `@FindBy(xpath = "//button[@id='lrn_assess_next_btn']")
 WebElement lnkNextBtn; `